# "Infinite" Loop with Timer

Tags: java, timer

I was wondering if anybody here knows how to make a seamlessly endless loop with shapes using a timer. Basically I'm trying to make a new set of moving shapes while the current set of shapes is moving so that it looks like it's just infinitely moving along the top of the screen. I have tried the `if` statements alongside the `public int getX(){return x;)}`, but I have not succeeded in doing so. Maybe it's possible to have a second timer linked with a second set of shapes and set a delay time? (However, I do not know how to go about writing a second timer and I do not know how to set a delay, help me??)

Any solutions or suggestions?

Here is an example, notice how the set of shapes is redrawn after all of the shapes pass the screen. This is not what I want. I want it to appear as if it were infinitely running along the top of the screen in smooth succession.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ExampleLoop extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ExampleLoop());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer(50, this);
    int x = 0, velX = 7;

    // CHRISTMAS THEME :D
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for (int z = 0; z <= 500; z += 100)
            g.fillRect(x + z, 0, 20, 20);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (x < 500) {
            velX = velX;
            x = x + velX;
        }
        else {
            x = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to edit that but it is too much of a mess.  1) Don't SHOUT at us. 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the site. Uhhhhmm I fixed my "SHOUT" lol sorry about that. Thank you to whoever edited the code structure :D

Comment: Maybe it's because you keep starting the Timer every loop?

Comment: Can you elaborate, Obicere? I will continue tinkering with the code.

Comment: The reason why I asked this question is because this code can be used as reference material. As in, people can elaborate on or implement the code and create something totally different and unique utilizing a similar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really figure out what going on in your code, but I reproduce the effect you're looking for. You can examine it. It runs.

What i did was make 5 different xPoints. You could have done this by using an array of int but I thouhgt it would be easier to read this way.

For each xPoint, I incremented each timer iteration. If the xPoint reached the screen width, I made it equal 0. Then repaint. I did that for all the points.

**Code Edited:** to use arrays and loops

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GreenRects extends JPanel {

    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;

    private static final int OFFSET = 100;
    private static final int SIZE = 20;
    private static final int INC = 5;

    int[] xPoints = new int[5];

    public GreenRects() {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++) {
            xPoints[i] = x;
            x += OFFSET;
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++) {
                    if (xPoints[i] + INC < SCREEN_WIDTH) {
                        xPoints[i] += INC;
                    } else {
                        xPoints[i] = 0;
                    }
                }

                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++) {
            g.fillRect(xPoints[i], 0, SIZE, SIZE);
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new GreenRects());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to create a new set of shapes? Just use an array of xPoints and loop through the array. I could've easily used the same code but instead of using different x variable just have an array of `int[] xPoints;`

Comment: Sorry about the earlier comment. Earlier, I had only just skimmed through your answer and commented in my eagerness. After studying your answer, it was, indeed, what I was looking for.

Comment: I ran your code and I don't quite understand why the frame appears off screen when the location was set relative to null. I'm curious if you know how to fix this.

Comment: Just use this instead `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);`. Also please don't forget to accept answer if this worked for you. (check mark below down-vote)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but the frame is still not centered on my screen -_-. Usually when I use frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); the frame is centered on my screen and I'm curious to know why this is not true for your code.

Comment: You need to `pack()` before setting location. Just switch it around

Comment: peeskillet, Do you have an e-mail address? I would like to ask a few more questions about code because you seem very intelligent.

Comment: I can't seem to find your e-mail address, maybe it's private?

Comment: Great!, I just sent you an e-mail :D

Comment: Hey peeskillet I ran into another similar problem. Can you help me out via e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code in if clause

```
if (x < 80)  
{
    velX = velX;
    x = x + velX;      
}
```

Comment: This didn't change anything, sorry.